# Configuring Content-Security-Policy header for grails 2.5 application

Tags: grails, clickjacking

I was going through different solutions available for preventing clickjacking in a grails application. One of the solutions was using X-Frame. So, I found a grails plugin, [X-Frame-Options Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/xframeoptions), by *mrhaki*.

It is serving my purpose of adding a response header

> X-Frame:DENY

to every response. Great!

I read there was a modern solution - Content-Security-Policy header. I'm unable to configure this for my Grails application. Could someone help?

Answer (score 2):

The X-Frame-Options plugin is simple and inserts a servlet filter to add a header to requests. For your situation I'd recommend creating your own servlet filter to add the Content-Security-Policy headers.

You can see an example here of how to add a header: 
https://github.com/mrhaki/grails-x-frame-options-plugin/blob/df230a9f01cd2e1c6ac4be6d9eac41fbcae48293/src/main/groovy/com/mrhaki/grails/plugin/xframeoptions/web/XFrameOptionsFilter.groovy#L69

Another option would be to use your web server infront of your app (apache httpd or nginx) to add the headers.

Comment: should i add something in resources groovy?