# Content security policy does not appear

Tags: tomcat, grails, content-security-policy

I would like to add content security policy to my project.

I saw this post:
[Configuring Content-Security-Policy header for grails 2.5 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49357233/configuring-content-security-policy-header-for-grails-2-5-application)

I installed this plugin to my project : https://grails.org/plugin/xframeoptions?skipRedirect=true

I added these line to config.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.xframeoptions.urlPattern = '/project_name/*'
grails.plugin.xframeoptions.deny = true
grails.plugin.xframeoptions.sameOrigin = true
grails.plugin.xframeoptions.enabled = true
```

I added this line to main.gsp

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

But I don't see security policy in the browser, how can I do it or configure on tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Grails is built on top of Spring Boot. I think you should be able to use directly [Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-csp) to manage CSP HTTP headers (or meta tag). (I don't know how to do it exactly, cas I don't have experience with Grails)

Using Spring Security you can configure [XFO header](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#websocket-sockjs-sameorigin) too, therefore you do not need any additional X-Frame-Options plugin.

Also if you publish CSP via HTTP header, you can use [frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) directive, it's much flexible than obsolete XFO header and overrides XFO (except [Safari](https://csplite.com/csp17/#bug_Safari_frame-ancestors_X-Frame-Options) browsers released before may 1, 2019).